# Python vlookup drop out duplicate rows

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'd like to use Vlookup in Python from different two excel files.

However, the result file showed me :

```
# original            # same data
col1 | col2 | col3 | col1 | col2 | col3
  1      2      3      1      2      3
  4      5      6      4      5      6
```

In short, it generated the same columns with same data at the end of original column after merge two excel files.

Desired output :

```
original
   col1 | col2 | col3
     1      2      3
     4      5      6
```

My code :

```
df1 = pd.read_excel("original.xlsx")
df2 = pd.read_excel("dropped.xlsx")


result = df2.merge(df1, on = 'col1', how='left')
result.columns = result.columns.str.replace('_x|_y','', regex=True)
result.to_excel("result.xlsx", index=False)
```

Comment: Can you post input sample data?

Comment: I think [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: MAybe is necessary explain why not possible merge by 3 columns `result = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], how='left'))` like used in previous question

Comment: so what happens with col3 on `dropped.xlsx` has a different value say, 9 instead of 3 can you show the result when there isnt a match?